# Callback in Visual Studio C++ Class Library

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013

I need to call native C++ from C#. One of the methods in C++ library needs to read web page content - i have decided to do it via **cURL** library. I have created a **Visual C++ -> CLR -> Class Library** project and now my library looks like this:

```
#pragma once    
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>

using namespace System;

namespace HtmlCppParser {

    public ref class HtmlCppParser
    {
    public:
        String^ GetContent(String^ url){
            CURL *curl;
            CURLcode res;
            String^ content;

            curl = curl_easy_init();
            if (curl) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, this->write_data);
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);
                res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
                curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

                return content;
            }
        }

    private:
        size_t write_data(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
        {
            ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
            return size * nmemb;
        }
    };
}
```

When i compile this one i get **C3867 Error:**

*error C3867: HtmlCppParser::HtmlCppParser::write_data:  function call missing argument list; use "&HtmlCppParser::HtmlCppParser::write_data"...*

Where is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution will be to make `write_data` a "classic" C-function (move it out of the `HtmlCppParser` class) and replace `this->write_data` by `&write_data`, because you seem to receive everything needed via the `userp` pointer.

And you should take care that you're supplying a `System::String` via `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);` but casting it to `std::string` inside of `write_data`. You should probably use `std::string` in `GetContent` too or probably replace both with [System::Text::StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).